# paperclip 5.1 content-type validation too strict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip-validation

I need to upload attachments with extension of .txt but evaluate to mime-type "application/octet-stream" by the file command. The file is automatically generated by a piece of equipment and it is not feasible to rename it before uploading. I have tried:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :excerpt
  validates_attachment_content_type :excerpt, content_type: { content_typ: ["text/plain", "application/octet-stream"]}
  validates_attachment_file_name :excerpt, matches: [/txt\z/]
end
```

but I always get an error that the detected content-type does not match the inferred content-type:

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/313a40bb0448477e051da1e2cba2c20120161027-19345-lrhf6t.txt'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Sample.txt (text/plain from Headers, ["text/plain"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

The error message says to look in documentation for a way to allow the combination but I have not been able to find anything that looks like a workaround. Saw this [discussion](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429) but it was for v4.

Answer (score 3):

Is it because of the misspelled `content_type` key? (You have it entered as `content_typ`.)

If the first suggestion doesn't work, I think that in your case, you'd want to do this in `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` (according to instructions in the README's [Security Validations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations) section):

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  txt: %w(text/plain application/octet-stream)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the pointer, Chris. Guess I didn't read that section of the README file carefully enough. (BTW, fixing the typo didn't make any difference.)

So, the solution is as follows:

In `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  txt: %w(application/octet-stream)
}
```

In the model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :excerpt
  validates_attachment_file_name :excerpt, matches: [/txt\z/]
end
```

This works whether the actual .txt file is a 'text/plain' or 'application/octet-stream'.